# Is it possible to vertically align text in a div with `display: -webkit-box;`

Tags: html, css, webkit, display

I'm working with a `div` which has the following css attribute assigned to it: `display: -webkit-box;`.

This `div` of mine contains text which I'd like to align vertically to the middle. Is this possible without changing the `display` attribute given to the div?

**Additional Info:**

I'm using the latest version of Chrome and have tried `vertical-align: middle;` which failed.

Comment: -webkit-box is a old and limited spec for flex. https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ Vertical alignment will work for a limited set of browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers/49145277#49145277

Comment: Which property? `display: -webkit-box'`? That's definitely a valid property. Look it up... It's usefull for multiline text ellipses wrapping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement works for me:

```
-webkit-box-align: center;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awt39v5s/1/

For the "old" flexbox definition, https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/ is a good resource.

Answer (score 9):

There are two cases of `-webkit-box-orient` depending on it's value:

1. `-webkit-box-orient: vertical`: you shoud use `-webkit-box-pack: center` to **vertical align** the text.
2. `-webkit-box-orient: horizontal`: you shoud use `-webkit-box-align: center` to **vertical align** the text.

All of these cases are similar to the alignment in `flexBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The children should be display block.
And use in parent element:

```
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-align: end;
```